# Do Adobe Air apps work in iphone and ipad ?

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, adobe, air

Do Adobe AIR apps work on iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 5):

Now you can reuse your AS3 code with [this](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/) Packager for iPhone.

Another way to compile Adobe AIR Apps for iPhone/iPad is to use [ELIPS](http://developer.openplug.com/about/blog/142-whats-coming-in-elips-studio) (I've never used it, but it looks promising).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Applications_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Actually they can work just fine – see [this](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/617244?tstart=0).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi, I will bare that in mind. Thanks for the heads up, appreciated.